# Prove $a^n - 1$ is composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove that $a^n - 1$ is a composite number when $a>2$ and $n\ge2$ ($a,n$ are integers). I have tried a few things, but couldn't make it.

Comment: Just divide it by $a-1$.

Comment: What does it mean to "proof" a number?

Comment: The question as originally posed made no sense. I am pleased that @Dave made some sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the factorization $$a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+1)$$

Comment: Can you explain why this factorization helps me?

Comment: What does it mean for a number to be composite?

Comment: I Understood how to do it, composite is not primary number. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^m-1=(x-1)(x^{m-1}+\dots 1)$.